# Does this combination problem count the repeats

Tags: combinatorics

To use a certain cash machine, you need a Personal Identification Code (PIC). If each PIC consists of two letters followed by one of the digits from 1 to 9 (such as AQ7 or BB3) or one letter followed by two digits (such as Q37 or J88), how many different PIC's can be assigned

Because they want different outcomes I believe the answer is 24x23x9+24x9x8.=$6696$.

How am I wrong? If we did 24x24x9.... we would have repeats with the first and second letters in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing "repeated PICs" with "repeated characters".

The number of unique PICs is $26\times26\times9 + 26\times9\times9$. The strings come in two disjoint sets: those with two letters and those with one. For those with two, we have $26$ choices for the first letter, $26$ for the second, and then $9$ choices for the digit. For those with two, we have $26$ choices for the letter, $9$ for the first digit, and then $9$ choices for the other.

What *you* are counting is the size of the subset of those PICs that never repeat a digit or character, which is $26\times25\times9 + 26\times9\times8$.

Comment: interestingly enough the problem gives you sample codes like BB3 where the letters repeat...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have shown BB3 and J88 as valid PICs, you should allow repetition of digits and letters.

So correct answer should be, 26*26*9+26*9*9

Why have you used 24 as number of choices of letters ?

Comment: I forgot the number of letters in the english alphabet. should't it be 26x25x9 + 26x9x8?   9x9 or 26x26 would indicate repeats, right?